# pandas dataframe early data typing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, types

I am trying to load relatively large amount of data from database and I wanted to optimize my dataframe by assigning appropriate data types before beginning the load. But so far what I could found was that I can only optimize data types after I have loaded the dataframe and I can see this happening from the below code. So if there is any other way of assigning the data types early that would really help me manage the memory requirements of my code.

```
dbdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Incr', 'Found'])
dbdf = dbdf.astype({'ID': str, 'Incr': np.int16, 'Found': str})

dbdf = pd.read_sql(
    'SELECT substring_index(ID, \'.\', 2) as ID, Incr, \'Y\' as Found FROM database.',
    conn, coerce_float=True)  # database dataframe

print('$$$$$BEFORE$$$$$')
print(dbdf.memory_usage())
print(dbdf.dtypes)

print('$$$$$AFTER$$$$$')
dbdf = dbdf.astype({'ID': np.float64, 'Incr': np.int16, 'Found': str})
print(dbdf.memory_usage())
print(dbdf.dtypes)
```

Below are the results

```
$$$$$BEFORE$$$$$
ID        6695328
Incr    6695328
Found      6695328
dtype: int64
ID        object
Incr     int64
found      object

$$$$$AFTER$$$$$
ID        6695328
Incr    1673832
Found      6695328
dtype: int64
ID        float64
Incr      int16
Found       object
```

Comment: I’m curious, how significant are the savings from having ID as a float64 rather than a string?

Comment: I can't seem to find a "string" type to see that even though my code specifies 'str' so I can tell the saving there, but even for 'Incr' I am not getting those saving during the load, I can only do that after df has been loaded. I am loading a table, just the above columns, with about 560 million records and my container with 8GB ram is running out. I am quite sure I can manage to load it in given memory but can't seem to assign the right types.

Comment: if you are able to load 560 million records, with a string column into 8 gig of ram on a single node you are my hero

Comment: hahahaha :) Thanks for killing my hopes. I just started working with Python and dataframes btw. Any suggestion on how to get 560 million records, made of ID (sample value: '2287.99999') + Incr (sample value: 345362) and Found (sample value: 'Y'), into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the type of the column before loading, then there are two options (as far I know :P).

1. Specify the type of the column using `cast` while reading the sql data. (I dont have knowledge on sql, so i am not sure about the syntax, so sorry about that)

`'SELECT cast (ID as float64()), cast (Incr as int()) FROM database'`

[refer the link](http://smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/convert.html)

2. Using the dtype argument to specify the type of the column.

`pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'ID': str, 'Incr': np.int16, 'Found': str}, conn, coerce_float=True)`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, I already tried casting in database. Panadas still applies it "default" types during the load. For the second option, I think you are mistaken with read_csv because that function has the dtype argument, read_sql has no such argument.